# How to place createMaterialTopTabNavigator, underneath to the drawer navigator and page title

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a mobile app using react native. I am using react navigation 4. I wanted to create a top bar navigation in a screen. That's why i used createMaterialTopTabNavigator. the top bas has two tab Ongoing and Finished. Now the top bar tab placed to the top of the app. But I want to place it underneath the left drawer navigator and the screen title. Please see this image. https://sarderitworld.com/demo/toptab.png

I am not getting any option for do this.

```
const deleveriesBottomTabWIthTopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
        OnGoing : DeleveriesOnGoingStackNavigator,
        Finished : DeleveriesFinishedStackNavigator
    })

const boottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Deleveries : deleveriesBottomTabWIthTopTabs,
        Request: RequestAsSenderStackNavigator
    })
```

I want to place the top tab bar underneath after the left drawer menu and screen title.

Comment: What is the connection between the Top Navigator and the Bottom Navigator? Stack? Switch?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that problem? I am having the same trouble as well. @hongdeveloper I am using Stack, as I only want the tabs to be working in one option of the drawer. I have created a question with the same subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350147/react-native-header-needs-to-be-on-top-of-creatematerialtoptabnavigator