# React Native: Header needs to be on top of createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-top-tabs

I am having some trouble related to createMaterialTopTabNavigator (react-navigation). I want to have my tabs navigator below the header, yet this is how it's currently shown:

[image: Header Error]

I don't have much knowledge about how I could bring the header down, as I need the header to be above the tabs navigator. Here is the main code for that part:

```
const EmptyLegsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainEmptyLegsScreen: {
      screen: MainEmptyLegScreen,
    },
    SecondaryScreen: {
      screen: SecondaryScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Empty Legs',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
      },
    },
  },
);

const QuotesNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainQuotesScreen: {
      screen: MainQuoteScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Quotes',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
      },
    },
  },
);

const FlightsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainFlightsScreen: {
      screen: MainFlightScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Flights',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
      },
    },
  },
);

const RegisterNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Register: RegisterScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Register',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
      },
    },
  },
);

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Login',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
      },
    },
  },
);

const tabScreenConfig = {
  EmptyLegs: {
    screen: EmptyLegsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Empty Legs',
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return <Icon name="airport" size={25} color="black" />;
      },
      tabBarColor: '#eee',
    },
  },
  Quotes: {
    screen: QuotesNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Quotes',
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return <Icon name="airplane" size={25} color="black" />;
      },
      tabBarColor: '#ddd',
    },
  },
  Flights: {
    screen: FlightsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Flights',
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return <Icon name="airplane-takeoff" size={25} color="black" />;
      },
      tabBarColor: '#ccc',
    },
  },
};

const MainTabNavigator =
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
    tabBarOptions: {},
  });

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
    Register: RegisterNavigator,
    Login: LoginNavigator,
  },
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red',
    },
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add padding on top of your root component.
You certainly have a App.js file where you import your MainNavigator.

```
...
import MainNavigator from 'yourMainNavigatorfile'

class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={paddingTop:20}> {/* You can use another paddingTop value depending of your screen size or Constants.statusBarHeight if you use Expo*/}
        <MainNavigator/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for the help. That solves the problem with the notch and shows the bar correctly, but the tabs are still on top of the header, and that is the issue I need to solve. The header needs to be on top of the tabs!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SafeAreaView instead of paddingTop.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView, View,
} from 'react-native';
import MainNavigator from './yourMainNavigatorfilePath'

class App extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <MainNavigator />
        </SafeAreaView>

        OR

        <View>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <MainNavigator />
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for the help. That solves the problem with the notch and shows the bar correctly, but the tabs are still on top of the header, and that is the issue I need to solve. The header needs to be on top of the tabs!

Comment: Can you share how you are adding tabs and Headers? So I'll be able to help you more on that.

Comment: Hey! I have added how I am adding the tabs and headers to the code above. First, I have added the options for the main drawer to the side. Then, in the MainTabNavigator, I have added the top tab navigator with the tabs I needed, and each individual tab has a stack that I shall be adding new screens in the future.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/move-tabs-under-header

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fragments and can return both (customer header and Top tab bar).

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
const TopTabNavigator = () => {
return (
  <Fragment>
  <YourCustomHeaderBar />
   <TopTab.Navigator>
    <TopTab.Screen name="Empty Legs" component={Screen1} />
    <TopTab.Screen name="Quotes" component={Screen2} />
    <TopTab.Screen name="Flights" component={Screen3} />
   </TopTab.Navigator>
  </Fragment>
 );
};
```

Comment: That is not the issue the issue is a safe area. And he is using react-navigation 4 or lower.

Comment: SafeAreaContext is also issue here but the main problem is he wants to add header on top of tab bar

Comment: For that nesting, it inside stack nav with header or react-navigation v6 is the best option.

Comment: What if you want to show Top Tab Bar on just single screen and you also have bottom tab bar which displays on all screens. How would you manage that?

Comment: `headerShow` property!